# How To Create A Custom ErrorDocument Page In Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, apache2, .htaccess

I am new to Ubuntu and I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04. Now I want to use my own design HTML web pages as my server status errors like on `404` etc. I tried my own way but not getting my designed page and I am getting server default error page when I am opening `192.168.1.99/404` that document is not available in my `var/www/` as attached below.

[image]

I have `index.html`, `404.html`, `.htaccess` files in my `var/www/` folder. My `.htaccess` files contain `ErrorDocument 404  /404.html` line only. I didn't change any default setting. I just install `Ubuntu Server 14.04` and using it via Terminal. Can you tell me what to do now?

Comment: see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/custom-error.html

Comment: @Rinzwind I know it and I tried it. Read my question again. But its not working.

Comment: @Rinzwind I didn't change any default setting. Yes. I restarted my Apache after adding `.htaccess` file codes using `service apache2 restart`. But still not showing my `404.html` page.

Comment: Remove the `/` from `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` in your .htaccess. I think that's your error.

Comment: @Parto I removed `/` and tried but not working.

Comment: (@Rinzwind & Parto) Finally I did it. You can also view the answer below.

Comment: Excellent @MuhammadHassan have an upvote from me and do not forget to accept your answer is a few hours :D

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks and its saying me to accept in 2 days. :P But I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I searched and tried myself and got my code working. I found that I am not activating `.htaccess` files in my Apache2 service. I did the following steps and got it working.

Step 1:) First Open `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` File To Edit.

Step 2:) Add The Below Codes Just Before `</VirtualHost>` And Save This File.

```
AccessFileName .htaccess (.htaccess is the default filename)
<Directory /var/www/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Step 3:) Now Restart The Apache Service Using Following Command In Terminal.

`service apache2 restart`

Step 4:) Its Done. Now Open Any File That Doesn't Exists And You Will Get Your Custom Designed Error File.

Note: Use the same `.htaccess` file as I added in my question.